# angular 5 - loop of observers inside an other observer - efficient way to do it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a 'get' call that returns a list of users that contains a user id and a name.
After the call succeeded, I need to call another rest for *each* user to bring his picture.

Currently I am doing this in this way-

component-

```
users;
userPhotos = {};

constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {
  this.dashboardService.bringUsers().subscribe((data) =>{
    this.users = data;
    this.users.forEach((user) => {
      this.dashboardService.getPicture(user.userID).subscribe((data) => {
        if (data){
          this.userPhotos[user.userID] = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        } else {
          this.userPhotos[user.userID] = '';
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

In my html-

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
  <div>
      {{user.displayName}}
  </div>

  <display-picture [image]="userPhotos[user.userID]"></display-picture>
</ng-container>
```

Where display-picture is a component that just presents the image.

Is there any efficient way using rxjs to do it?

Comment: This should ideally be implemented by the Backend APIs that you're leveraging. The API should also respond with the display pictures for each user as a part of the initial request.

Comment: But I don't want that the my initial request will be delayed because of the pictures, that may be more heavy to bring.

Comment: IMHO, I think it's better to get all the data that you have to show in a single view at once as opposed to making multiple API calls to get different fields. It's just a matter of what needs to be shown together. If the case was to show only names in a view and then once the user clicks on an item, and then you show them another view , the current API implementation would have scaled better. But if you need the names and the images all in a single view, then this approach won't scale well. Hence, I'd suggest you to reconsider the strategy based on how your UI needs to look.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I agree. This is clearly associated data, and a good API should support appending associated data. So a single request for "users" should have included the "photos" that belong to those users. Doesn't matter how you implement it Java/PHP/C# or GraphGL. If you have to change the API everytime the front-end changes your back-end developers will forever be updating the API.

Comment: @Reactgular, yeap. I think OP should consider GraphQL in that case.

Comment: ok, but how a rest api can produce a json and also "image/png" together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from` to iterate each user and `mergeScan` can be used here to execute the observables. For clarity i break it into two functions. You can also control the number of concurrency with `mergeScan`

```
    const getUserPic=users=>from(users).pipe(
        mergeScan((acc, curr:any) =>
            getPicture(curr.userID).pipe(map(photo => {
                acc[curr.userID] = photo
                return acc
            }))
          ,{})
        ) 

bringUsers().pipe(
    tap(users=>this.users=users),
    switchMap(users=> getUserPic(users)),
    last()
).subscribe(console.log)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-1bt172

Comment: In this way do I have my initial users object? it can have not only the display name.

Comment: it is assigned to this.users or you can pass it along the chain if you want ..  something like  `switchMap(users=> getUserPic(users).pipe(map(userPics=>({userPics,users}))...`

Comment: I tried to implement it exactly as you said but for some reason I have an error that mergeScan expects 2-3 arguments, and another problem (maybe because of that) I do not see any request sent to the server,

Comment: I try to come up with an working example in stack Liz

Comment: updated the answer and working example. mocked the api. Hope you get the idea

Comment: Many thanks! and is there a simple way to save my "users"> I need to display in on the screen?

Comment: Assign it to this.users in angular is the simplest. There is also async pipe that u can use

Comment: I tried to do it in here- this.dashboardService.bla().pipe(
            switchMap(users=>
                getUserPic(users);
                this.users = users;
            
            ),
            last()
        ).subscribe(console.log);

But I get errors

Comment: I do not want to call again to this rest.

Comment: Just one more question- is your way is more efficient/more preferred than my way?

Comment: Your approach is ok too, but functional approach u don’t need to have too many local variable defined and the data flow is more explicit and enclosed.

Comment: but in the end I need also the users variable and the userImage variable so I can display them both in my app. because of this I have changed it to-
        bringUsers().pipe(
            tap(users=>this.users=users),
            switchMap(users=> getUserPic(users)),
            last()
        ).subscribe(photos=>{
            this.userPhotos = photos;
        });

Comment: Ya you also attach a tap after last() to do that too

Comment: So to use a tap after the "subscribe" instead of just assigning photos to this.userPhotos or I did ok?

Comment: What u did is ok too, tap is a side effect operator that is best use for assigning something outside of observable chain

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [forkJoin()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to merge together all the final emitted values from multiple observables. RxJS 6 supports using an object map of key/value pairs to define which observables, but you'll have to use an array for older versions.

```js
this.dashboardService.bringUsers().pipe(
   switchMap(users => forkJoin(
       users.reduce((acc, user) => (acc[user.userId] = this.dashboardService.getPicture(user.userID), acc), {}
   ))),
).subscribe((users: {[userId: number]: any}) => {
   Object.entries(users).forEach(([userId, data]:[number,any]) => {
      this.userPhotos[user.userID] = data ? window.URL.createObjectURL(data) : '';
   });
});
```

Comment: Why do I need an array of older versions?

Comment: Why reduce? it looks like I am losing my "users" object in this methid. I need the original "users" as well.

Comment: as of rxjs 6.5 forkjoin support handling array of objects with observable as object value, reduce is there to produce a {key:pictureObservable}  array for forkJoin to work on
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html